# Why is the equality $\int_{-a}^0 f(x) \, dx = \int_0^a f(-x) \, dx$ holds?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{-a}^0 f(x) \, dx = \int_0^a f(-x) \, dx$$

For LHS we get: $$F(0) - F(-a)$$

Whereas, for RHS we get: $$F(-a)-F(0)$$

I can understand that the justification is that it doesn't matter how we sum, from right to left or from left to right, but Newton-Leibnitz seems like a contradiction.

Comment: $f(-x)$ and $f(x)$ need not have the same antiderivative.

Comment: You can note that $F'(-x)=-f(-x).$

Comment: Oh right. That was nonsense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $x=-y$

$\int _{-a}^0 f(x)=\int _a^0 f(-y)(-dy)=\int _0^{a}f(-y)dy=\int _0^ af(-x) dx$

Answer (score 1):

The right hand side:

$$\int^a_0 f(-x)dx=-\int^{-a}_0 f(-x)d(-x)=-(F(-a)-F(0))=F(0)-F(a)$$

So they are the same.